# How to recode several values for a specific row tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

I would like to find a way to change values in several columns for a specific row using `tidyverse`.
For example, with `base` `R` and the `iris` dataset:

```
iris[iris$Sepal.Length == 5.1, c("Petal.Length",
                                 "Petal.Width")] <- c(1.5,
                                                      0.5)
```

So far, I found this with `tidyverse`, but how to change these values for only the row where `Sepal.Length == 5.1`? I know I could `filter` the row that I want and then change the values, but what if I want to keep the whole dataset as in the `base` example above?:

```
myiris <- iris %>% 
 mutate_at(c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width"),
 funs(recode(., "1.4" = 1.5, "0.2" = 0.5)))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work, it's not the most elegant, but it worked for me:

```
library(tidyverse)

myiris <- iris %>% 
  mutate_at(c("Petal.Length","Petal.Width"),
      funs(ifelse(Sepal.Length == 5.1, c(1.5, 0.5), c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))))
```